# How to find all the unsupported and unmodifiable parameters in RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-administration

We are moving from a MySQL DB to RDS MySQL DB. I find that many of the parameters we have on the current MySQL DB are not available on the RDS.

For example, unmodifiable db parameter - auto_generate_certs,
invalid/unsupported db parameter - audit_log_buffer_size

We are finding about these parameters piecemeal, we run one cloud formation, we get error about one parameter, then we run another one we find about another one. Is there any way we can get the info about this in one go from some place?

Answer (score 1):

If you log in to AWS Console, and navigate to RDS -> Parameter groups, then click open the parameter group being modified, you will see that there is a column denoting whether the parameter is modifiable.

Comment: So, whatever parameters are there in the parameter group, only those can be used on the RDS. No other parameters, even if they may be supported on a normal on-prem mysqlDB.